# SOAP API call with PHP, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"!

Tags: php, api, object, soap

We are trying to integrate our code with and SMS Provider.
They provided a SOAP API but we ran to a problem and we couldn't figure out the cause. Regretfully the SMS provider couldn't answer our issue as well.

So here's the problem:

We are trying to call the '**SaveNewSchedulSendSms_Daily**' API:

```
class ScheduleSend_Daily
{
    public $Id;
    public $MessageBody;
    public $FromDate;
    public $FromDate_Date;
    public $FromDate_Time;
    public $ToDate;
    public $ToDate_Date;
    public $ToDate_Time;
    public $Time;
    public $SmsLineID;
    public $MobileNumbers;
    public $IsFlash;
    public $IsChecked;
    public $SendType;
    public $SmsSendType;
}

$ScheduleSend_Daily = new ScheduleSend_Daily();
$ScheduleSend_Daily->Id = '-1';
$ScheduleSend_Daily->MessageBody = $SMS_TEXT;
$ScheduleSend_Daily->FromDate = $DATE_TIME[0].'T00:00:00';
$ScheduleSend_Daily->FromDate_Date = $DATE_TIME[0];
$ScheduleSend_Daily->FromDate_Time = '00:00:00';
$ScheduleSend_Daily->ToDate = $DATE_TIME[0].'T23:59:59';
$ScheduleSend_Daily->ToDate_Date = $DATE_TIME[0];
$ScheduleSend_Daily->ToDate_Time = '23:59:59';
$ScheduleSend_Daily->Time = $DATE_TIME[0].'T'.$DATE_TIME[1].':00';
$ScheduleSend_Daily->SmsLineID = LINE_NUMBER;
$ScheduleSend_Daily->MobileNumbers = array (doubleval(USER_NUMBER));
$ScheduleSend_Daily->IsFlash = 0;
$ScheduleSend_Daily->IsChecked = 0;
$ScheduleSend_Daily->SendType = 'SendOnSchedule_Daily';
$ScheduleSend_Daily->SmsSendType = 'SendOnSchedule_Daily';

$client = new SoapClient('http://ip.sms.ir/ws/SendReceive.asmx?wsdl');
$params = array (
    'userName' => SMS_USERNAME,
    'password' => SMS_PASSWORD,
    'DailyScheduleSend' => $ScheduleSend_Daily);
$result = $client->SaveNewSchedulSendSms_Daily($params);
```

**NOTE**: they are asking us to send the datetime as 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss'

This will result in the following error

```
stdClass Object
(
    [SaveNewSchedulSendSms_DailyResult] => -10
    [message] => Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
)
```

So, what causing this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have added the missing parameters to object.
Thanks @PratikSoni to pointing this out.
It also needs 'IsChecked' parameter which is weird!

Now I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 344). ---> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32. at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read9_ScheduleSend_Daily(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read33_SaveNewSchedulSendSms_Daily() at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer20.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader) at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingSt
```

Comment: Can you try `dailyScheduleSend` instead of DailyScheduleSend.

Comment: Hey @PratikSoni, now it giving us the following error  `Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'IsChecked' property`

Comment: `$ScheduleSend_Daily = new ScheduleSend_Daily();
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->Id = '-1';
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->MessageBody = $SMS_TEXT;
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->FromDate = $DATE_TIME[0].'T00:00:00';
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->FromDate_Time = $DATE_TIME[0].'T00:00:00';
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->ToDate = $DATE_TIME[0].'T23:59:59';
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->ToDate_Time = $DATE_TIME[0].'T23:59:59';
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->Time = $DATE_TIME[0].'T'.$DATE_TIME[1].':00';
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->SmsLineID = LINE_NUMBER;
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->MobileNumbers = array (doubleval(USER_NUMBER));`

Comment: `$ScheduleSend_Daily->IsFlash = 0;
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->IsChecked = 0;
  $ScheduleSend_Daily->SmsSentTypes = 'SendOnSchedule_Daily';`

Comment: Use all missing parameters and try again.

Comment: OK, it needed 2 more parameteres FromDate_Time & ToDate_Time

Comment: now it gives me this: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 344). ---> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

Comment: Try to use value around 10000 for Id

Answer (score 0):

You have passed incorrect parameters and number of parameters should be same as required in the soap call.

Here is the list of all parameters you have to pass.

```
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SmsLineID" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MobileNumbers" type="tns:ArrayOfLong"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SmsSendType" type="tns:SMSSentTypes"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Time" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="IsFlash" type="s:boolean"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ToDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FromDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MessageBody" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Id" type="s:long"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SendType" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FromDate_Time" type="tns:TimeSpan"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ToDate_Time" type="tns:TimeSpan"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FromDate_Date" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ToDate_Date" type="s:string"/>
```

Keep in mind the name is the parameter you are going to pass from your side.

Comment: Thanks @PratikSoni. I've changed the unnecessary parameters to NULL and now it is working!